# give code to validate textbox if the textbox not contains the value except "mm-dd-yyyy" fromate it shoud display error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

give code to validate textbox if the textbox not contains the value except "mm-dd-yyyy" fromate it shoud display error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Regular Expression validator control, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx). And matching [dates with regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) is a very common task.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link [Javascript mm/dd/yyy link](http://www.smartwebby.com/dhtml/date_validation.asp)

To convert it into the "mm-dd-yyyy" format just comment out(or replace) this code

```
var dtCh= "/";
```

And Add or With

```
var dtCh= "-";
```